# how to recreate folder in script inside package.json on Windows

Tags: node.js, powershell

The goal is to delete the public folder and then to recreate it before building the application.

This should work also if the folder does not exist yet.

I have this script in package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "prebuild": "rm -rf public && mkdir public"
}
```

it works nicely on mac and linux

how can I get it to work on Windows, preferably in powershell?

Comment: Run some js instead of cli commands.

Comment: just an FYI.. since you are working on Mac, too. You don't have to delete the directory first, at least on OSX Sierra.
'mkdir -p public' avoids the initial delete.

Answer (score 2):

this here seems to work best:

```
"scripts": {
    "prebuild": "rmdir /Q /S public && mkdir public"
}
```

only problem: an error occurs if the folder "public" does not exist yet

Answer (score 0):

```
if (test-path public) { rmdir public; mkdir public}
```

Or

```
if (test-path public) { Remove-Item public; Create-Item -Directory public}
```

Or

```
mkdir blank;robocopy /MIR blank public;rmdir blank
```

Or

```
Create-Item -Directory blank; robocopy /MIR blank public; Remove-Item blank
```

I think the last one is the most appropriate.  Of course 'public' will probably need to be set as a relative or absolute path.

And using the linux aliases probably only works in the powershell shell or gui.  To see the PowerShell equivalent of most commands, just `Get-Alias <command>`.

Comment: I get errors with all above versions. Not in powershell itself but when rund as "npm rund prebuild"